# How to run flask app in existing dockerfile? How do I have flask run another application?

Tags: docker, flask

I have a docker file that looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /var/<some_project>

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/var/<some_project>"
ENV FLASK_APP "app/prometheus/__init__.py"

COPY app ./app
COPY sources ./sources
COPY *.py ./
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "sources/passport/main.py"]
```

I need to run flask run at some point to see my endpoint that I created in flask (under the folder app). What do I do to add this to this dockerfile?

I think I'm also going to have to have flask run the other `main` application because flask is exposing data that the other application is collecting. How do I have flask call the other application and have it run in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you don't want that enrypoint (maybe you do want it, but unless it's going to call flask itself I imagine it's a mistake).

I would rewrite the file like this:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /var/<some_project>

ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/var/<some_project>"
ENV FLASK_APP="app/prometheus/__init__.py"

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY app ./app
COPY sources ./sources
COPY *.py ./

CMD flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

You're going to need to replace `/var/<some_project>` with the actual name and you need to set `FLASK_APP` to an absolute path.

Since you have `FLASK_APP` set you should just need `CMD flask run` to run the app.

I also changed the order of your file copies and pip install to help with build caching.

Comment: I see I think I'm also going to have to have flask run the other application because flask is exposing data that the other application is collecting. How do I have flask call the other application and have it run in the background?

Comment: To clarify, the `main` application needs to run in the background because it is collecting data that flask needs to expose. How do I do this?

Comment: @Jwan622 you have two choices. You could just run them both. So you could replace CMD with `CMD python sources/passport/main.py & flask run --host=0.0.0.0` and then main.py would be running in the background. You can spawn many processes in a container. Otherwise, it's more common in the docker world to run one thing per container. So you would write two dockerfiles and run each script in its own container. If they need to communicate with each other they could do so over the network or through shared files with volumes.

Comment: I think I misunderstood my own problem. If I run them in two separate processes... they won't share some common state and that's a problem. Flask is meant to expose some data that the `main.py` is collecting. So, mind taking a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316880/how-to-start-a-flask-app-from-within-a-python-script-in-a-separate-thread

Comment: Hmm. Yeah there are a lot of ways you could go about doing this. If your flask server and your script are different python scripts I think it gets a lot more complicated. Flask is just python, you should try and combine your flask server and your main.py script. From there you could figure out how to share the data. Either in a globally shared value or some other method. You would need to use async/threads/multiprocessing to get the server and your task to run at the same time, but I think that's less complicated than figuring out how to make two python processes communicate.

Comment: Also suggested that you don't create new stackoverflow questions with sub-questions. (but it seems to have been pretty effective in this case :) )