# How to start a flask app from within a python script in a separate thread?

Tags: python, flask

I have a script that is extracting data from an internal service and storing the count of data types in memory like this:

```
metrics = {
   "new_accounts": 152,
   "acquisitions": 2005,
   ...
}
```

That is being done in memory and that whole process is kicked off by the `subscribe` method in this script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    for signal in [signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIGINT]:
        loop.add_signal_handler(
            signal, lambda s=signal: asyncio.create_task(close_subscriptions(s, loop)))

    for subscription in SUBSCRIPTION_TYPES:
        loop.create_task(subscribe(subscription))
    loop.run_forever()
```

I want to expose that `metrics` data through an endpoint in flask for monitoring purposes. In a thread, can I start the flask app in this script like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ...
    for subscription in SUBSCRIPTION_TYPES:
        loop.create_task(subscribe(subscription))
    ... <start flask app in a separate thread>
    loop.run_forever()
```

Does this make sense? I already have the flask app running locally but it doesn't have access to this `metrics` data. Is this the way I need to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put Your metric to Queue:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

Flask endpoint can read all data from Queue, and expose last value as endpoint data

Cheers, Fenrir

Comment: But they need to be on the same process right? Don't I need to spin off a thread of execution for the flask app so that the application in `main.py` can collect data?

Comment: I would suggest to put all stuff related with Your metric data handling to separate thread, using Queue You can get data. You can check my repo, I was working with similar problem - running API and have background task to refresh data, maybe it can help You. Its Django, but idea is silimar: https://github.com/t1waz/gwp_t1waz, check worker and how it starts in urls.py. Hope it will help You